# Kotlin + Retrofit + OkHttpでTimeoutを設定したい

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

表題のとおりで、Kotlin + Retrofit + OkHttpの環境でAPI接続する際に、インターネットに非接続状態（もしくはサーバーにトラブルがあった場合）でも設定したtimeoutの時間まで通信を行うようにしたいです。

OkHttpClientを下記のように設定したのですが、通信できない場合にすぐにエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
fun builderHttpClient(access_token: String): OkHttpClient {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(BearerAuthenticationInterceptor(access_token)) 
        return client.build()
    }


fun getRetrofit(access_token: String): Retrofit {
        val client = builderHttpClient(access_token)
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        return retrofit
    }


val service = retrofit.create(sample::class.java)
service.api()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(object : Subscriber<String>() {
    override fun onNext(p0: String) {}
    override fun onCompleted() {}
    override fun onError(p0: Throwable) {}
    }
)
}
```

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "サーバー名": No address associated with hostname

ご教示いただければと思います。

Comment: タイムアウトの設定は通信経路やサーバからの応答がない場合に、クライアント側から明示的に切断させる機能です。成功失敗を問わず、通信経路やサーバから応答があればタイムアウトの設定は影響を与えません。おそらく実現したいことはタイムアウトを設定することではなく、指定した時間の間で通信のリトライ処理を行うことではないでしょうか？そうであれば質問内容を編集して頂くと適切な回答がつきやすいかと思います。

Comment: 返事遅くなり申し訳ございません。私が勘違いしていたようです。教えていただいた方法で再度、調査してみようと思います。